# VBA to search in a list of TXT files and return text right after it

Tags: vba

Here's my code. It returns the name of the .txt file where the word "MAGIC" was found. Is there any way to bring the text that comes after the string found?

```
Sub StringExistsInFile()
    Dim theString As String
    Dim path As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim file As TextStream
    Dim line As String

    theString = "MAGIC"
    path = "C:\MyDownloads\*.log"
    StrFile = Dir(path & "*.log")

    Do While StrFile <> ""

        'Find TheString in the file
        'If found, debug.print and exit loop

        Set file = fso.OpenTextFile(path & StrFile)
        Do While Not file.AtEndOfLine
            line = file.ReadLine
            If InStr(1, line, theString, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print StrFile
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        file.Close
        Set file = Nothing
        Set fso = Nothing

        StrFile = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bring the text that comes after the string found".  Do you mean the line that it was found on? The rest of the file after the word? Something else?

Comment: The rest of the file after the word Magic until a specified length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim lPosition as Long
Dim sAfterMagic as String

lPosition = InStr(1, Line, theString, vbTextCompare)'Get position of Magic
sAfterMagic = Mid(theString, lPosition + 6)'Get text after Magic
```

I should clarify the objective here. You want to find the position of the word "Magic" within your string. To do this you use the InStr function. This returns a numeric position of where the text you are looking for is found. It actually returns the position of where the word starts. In this case the position will be at the letter (M) for "Magic".

To get anything after the word "Magic" you use the MID function. This allows you to return any part of a string by using a starting point that you specify. In this case we want anything after the word "Magic" so you take the numeric value found during INSTR and add the length of your search word; "Magic" which is 5 characters, and then add 1 to that (6 characters in total) so as to start at the first position after the letter "C".

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Good point. I was clearly too direct. An explanation was warranted.

Comment: Maybe there is an errore on second line, I think you should address "Line" instead of "theString" , you should get last 6 char from "Line," right?